# JavaScript for loop prints unexpected iterator value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I'm writing `function objectify(str)` which takes a string, turns it into an array and creates a new object with the key value pairs as the word and index of the array respectively, eg.

```
objectify('the cat sat on the mat')
```

=> { the: 0, cat: 1, sat: 2, on: 3, mat: 4 }

I wrote the function like this:

```
function objectify(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var object = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    object[words[i]] = i;
  }
  return object;
}
```

which printed:

=> { the: 4, cat: 1, sat: 2, on: 3, mat: 5 }

**Q1. What is `i` doing in this case?**

I know for the output I want the function needs to be written like so:

```
function countWords(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var object = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    object[words[i]] = words.indexOf(words[i]);
  }
  return object;
}
```

**Q2. Is there a more elegant way to do this?**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that "the" appears in the phrase twice, and your loop works in ascending order.  The second instance of "the" will update the `the` property to the larger value.  Sounds like you don't want that.  Instead, it sounds like you want the smaller value to take precedence.

You have two options.

**Do it backwards**.  Smaller values will take precedence because they will overwrite the larger values.

```
function objectify(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var object = {}
  for (var i = words.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
    object[words[i]] = i;
  }
  return object;
}
```

**Check for existence**.  Prevent larger values from overwriting smaller values by ensuring that the property isn't already defined.

```
function objectify(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var object = {}
  for (var i = 0; i<words.length; i++) {
    if (!object.hasOwnProperty(words[i])) {
      object[words[i]] = i;
    }
  }
  return object;
}
```